# How to add metadata to message in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I want to log events of sending and receiving message and use them to make some sort of visualization of whole messaging process. However, I have problem implementing reliable way of pairing those two events:

- at both dispatch and arrival I only dispose current actor and message, the later being the only thing available during both events,
- for now I use message type and hashcode but it's unreliable - overriding hashcode, sending message from remote actor or reusing the same message would make it impossible to pair events correctly,
- I was suggested to use timestamp but duration of the transmission is nonzero and that would be merely heuristic.

The only reliable way would be to attach some unique information to each message, and use it to connect the events, but manually wrapping and unwrapping each message would be inelegant and error prone.

Is there some way to add metadata to the message? Or any other mean to reliably pair up events of sending and receiving message?

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

```
object foo {

    // ID has a public getter and private setter
    trait Msg {
      private var _id = 0
      def id = _id
      private[foo] def id_=(value: Int): Unit = _id = value
    }

    // Companion object for the creation of Foo with an ID
    object Foo {
      def apply(id: Int, s: String): Foo = {
        val msg = Foo(s)
        msg.id = id
        msg
      }
    }

    // Private constructor => must be created from companion object
    case class Foo private (s: String) extends Msg

}

val msg = foo.Foo(42, "hello")
println(msg)
println(msg.id)
```

Output:

```
Foo(hello)
42
```

Make all your messages extend the Msg trait.
This way the ID can be set only during the creation of the message, then it's read-only.

Comment: Well, that's sufficient approach when we are developing new project and you can establish some sort of convention. However, when it comes to existing one, adding a trait to every single message might be a bit inconvenient. At the moment I already have to add a trait to each Actor and I'm looking for way to get rid of that as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that right now there is no 'out-of-the-box' way to add metadata to messages/case classes. Your only option are: 1) my solution 2) wrap in another case class.